# Spring MVC + mysql не запускается в Докере

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose

Имеется Spring MVC приложение которое работает с БД mysql. На локальной машине запускаю - все работает. Запуск осуществляется с помощью команды "mvn package" (в pom файле прикручен плагин, который скачивает Tomcat и запускает его на порту и URL из properties файла).

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <container>
              <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
              <type>embedded</type>
            </container>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <cargo.servlet.port>${servlet.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>${tomcat.url}</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
            <deployables>
              <deployable>
                <groupId>com.had0uken</groupId>
                <artifactId>english</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
                <properties>
                  <context>/</context>
                </properties>
              </deployable>
            </deployables>
          </configuration>

          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Пытаюсь теперь запустить его в докере. Задача: запустить mysql, создать там пользователя, залить дамп и после этого запустить приложение с помощью Maven. Имеется следующая структура папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Dockerfile в english_education выглядит следующим образом:

```
# Use Ubuntu 22.04 as the base image
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install JDK 18
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-18-jdk

# Install Apache Maven 3.6.0
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y maven

# Set the environment variables
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven

# Add the Maven bin directory to the PATH environment variable
ENV PATH $MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH


WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
COPY application.properties ./src/main/resources/

RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

EXPOSE 8084
```

Собственно качаем jdk, maven, копируем pom.xml, папку с приложением и копируем с заменой (или нет) видоизмененный файл properties, который выглядит так:

```
dataSource.driverClass = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/my_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
dataSource.user = bestuser
dataSource.password = bestuser
servlet.port = 8084
tomcat.url = http://localhost:8084
```

тут первый вопрос. Какой адрес нужно указать в tomcat.url? На локальной машине я его запускаю на локалхосте, а в докере где должен? Локал хост? Или tomcat.url = http://app:8084 (по названию сервиса)??

Дальше имеется docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

  app:
    build:
      context: ./english_education
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
 

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
```

В нем мы запускаем mysql, создаем usera bestuser, заливаем дамп в volumes. Потом запускаем сам сервис app. При запуске, я вижу что mysql и adminer запустились (status - Running), а app нет (status Excited). И по http://localhost:8084/ я никуда достучатся не могу с локальной машины. И получается еще два вопроса:

1. Где я допустил ошибку? Почему не стартует app?
2. Как можно посмотреть что происходит после команды mvn package? Чтобы я мог понять что не так?

Приветствуются любые идеи, советы
Если нужно добавить еще какую-то информацию, сообщите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В докере образ сначала собирается, а потом из него запускается контейнер.

Главная проблема у вас в том, что запускаете приложение на этапе сборки образа докер. А нужно на этапе запуска.

Для этого уберите конфигурацю, которая запускает приложение во время фазы package из конфигурации плагина cargo, т.е. уберите все секцию `executions`.

Теперь чтоб запустить приложение нужно будет явно дать команду на запуск. В актуальной версии плагина (3) собственно команда запуска выглядит так:

```
mvn org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven3-plugin:run
```

Собрать и запустить, т.е. сделать то, что раньше делала у вас `mvn clean package`, можно так:

```
mvn clean package org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven3-plugin:run
```

Вы используете устаревшую версию плагина 2, к ней документацию я сходу не нашел, вероятно, команда запуска это:

```
mvn org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run
```

Далее нужно добавить эту команду, как команду запуска для контейнера. Для этого в конец докер файла добавьте:

```
CMD mvn org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run
```

Что касается `tomcat.url`, то чтоб точно ответить нужно знать, как это свойство используется, это нестандартное свойство. Но скорее всего нужно указывать localhost, т.к. к контейнеру по имени могут обращаться только другие контейнеры запущенные из docker-compose файла, а тут это не то, что может происходить.

Могу предположить, что это свойство используется для генерации внешних ссылок на ресурсы приложения, в этом случае нужно использовать доменное имя, по которому приложение доступно для пользователей. Это значит, что значение зависит от того, для чего вы используете docker. Если только для локального запуска, то `http://localhost:8084` годится. Если же это будет использовано и на проде, то параметр нельзя прошивать жестко в файле, а нужно передавать как параметр конфигурации, чтоб можно было поменять.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Использовал RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

CMD mvn org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run и смог добраться до консоли и уже получив всю информацию поправил остальные ошибки и все заработало!